# Parent entity inheritance and inverse relationships using core data

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, core-data

I'm a bit new to core data and am currently trying to utilize parent entities.
Right now, I have this kind of model

> Entities:
>
> ThemePark -> hasAttractions (one to many relationship)
>
> WaterPark -> hasAttractions (one to many relationship)
>
> Attractions -> inThemePark (inverse relationship of hasAttractions)
>
> Attractions -> inWaterPark (inverse relationship of hasAttractions)

What I want to have is a parent entity, let's say GenericPark, that has the property "hasAttractions", but I'm not sure how the inverse relationship should be defined.

If I do the following

> Attractions -> inGenericPark (inverse of hasAttractions in GenericPark)

how can I figure out whether the GenericPark is a waterPark or a ThemePark?

How should I go about revising this model while utilizing parent entities?

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should assign a custom class to each entity in the Data Model Inspector (which can have the same name as the entity), and create NSManagedObject subclasses for each entity (if you have not done that already).

Then `ThemePark` and `WaterPark` are both subclasses of `GenericParc`, and you can test a `GenericParc` object e.g. with

```
if ([genericParc isKindOfClass:[ThemeParc class]]) {
    // It is a ThemePark:
    ThemeParc *themePark = (ThemeParc *)genericPark;
    // ... 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Every `NSManagedObject` instance, whether you've defined custom subclasses or not, has an associated `NSEntityDescription` that will tell you what kind of object it is. Just call [`-entity`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObject_Class/Reference/NSManagedObject.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001171-BAJCICGE) on the managed object in question.

For example:

```
if ([@"WaterPark" isEqualToString:[[somePark entity] name]]) {
  // do watery things
}
```